# Evaluate $\int e^{9x-2}dx$ using $u$ substitution

Tags: calculus, integration, solution-verification

Section 5.3

Evaluate $\int e^{9x-2}dx$ using $u$ substitution.

Can somebody verify this for me? Thanks!

---

Let $u=9x-2$. Then $\frac{du}{dx}=9$ and so $\frac{du}{9}=dx$. Thus we have:

$\int e^{9x-2}dx$

$= \int e^u \frac{du}{9}$

$= \frac{1}{9} \int e^u du$

$=\frac{1}{9} e^u + C$

$=\frac{1}{9}e^{9x-2}+C$

Comment: Your solution is correct.

Comment: You can just differentiate your answer to check if it matches the original function!

Comment: The time you take to write down your transformations is much longer than it would take you to either differentiate direnctly your expressions or to use a CAS like Wolfram-Alpha to do the differenciation.

Comment: I agree OP should check by differentiating. That said, it won’t catch all errors, such as forgetting the constant, or coming up with the correct answer coincidentally using an invalid method.